# why does the compare method of bcrypt returns false even when i enter the right password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

I am using Postman to test the login API. The register API works fine and hashes the password before saving it to the database. but when I try to log in with the same credentials, it says the password does not match.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    email: {
        type:String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true, 
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true, 
        lowercase: true,
        minlength: 6
    }
});
```

This is the middleware to encrypt the password

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {

    try{
        const user = this;
        if (!user.isModified("password")) {
          return next();
        }
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }

  });
```

This is the login functionality. whenever I enter a correct username and password, it says wrong password.

````
try{
        const {username, password} = req.body;
        const { error } = loginValidation.validate(req.body);
    
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: error.details[0].message, type: "error"});
        }
    
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
        
        if (!existingUser){
            return res.status(401).json({message:"Invalid username", type:"error"});
        }

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);
        if(!passwordMatch){
            return res.status(401).json({message:"Invalid password", type:"error"});
        }

        res.status(200).json({message: "Login successful", type:"success"});

    }catch(error){
        console.log(error.message + "Error from controllers/auth.js");
        res.status(500).json({message:"Error authenticating user", type:"error"});
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are converting the password to lowercase in the schema. Remove `lowercase: true` in the password field and try it again.

Comment: okay, I tried it and it worked. but I don't understand why it would not work with lowercase true. cause the password I was signing up with was all lowercase.

Comment: When you are working with bcrypt, you have to image that the password that will be stored in your database will be completely different from the password that the user types in. For example, if the password typed in is "12345678", you might end up with a password like "$2a$12$rNRMtYQNeZMHIuQYiPiQjetr193RJw3q3gocCt7I9TGoq5Yrz4vyG" being stored in your database. If you want to check that the user is only putting in lowercase letters, you could do that in form validation and also validation on the backend with something like Joi